# Can the help center be clarified on Lilypond?

Tags: discussion, topics, lilypond, help-center

There has been some confusation as to if Lilypond questions belong here. For example, [On which site are LilyPond questions on-topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168297/192187) Could we clarify in the [help center](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that these questions are perfectly on-topic here?

Comment: The intention is that `usage of specific music software` covers this...

Comment: Yes, I wish that would suffice as well. However for some people, that isn't clear enough. :( Supposedly, it's a file format (though that really should still fall into the software category).

Comment: Related question http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/32/would-a-question-about-music-notation-software-be-on-topic/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the generic "usage of specific music software" rather than calling out Lilypond,which  would require calling out other similar (Finale, Sibelius) and dissimilar (maybe Rosegarden, Abelton Live*) software.  This can be easily interpreted as an a priori limit on what software is valid to be discussed here.

I'm under the impression that the intent of this site that that which questions are "perfectly on-topic" is supposed to grow organically.  Thus we don't want an explicit white-list, or black-list for that matter.

*I'm just throwing out examples of music related software; I'm not trying to make any comment regarding which software discussions properly belong here or elsewhere.